# Linear diophantic equation

Tags: euclidean-algorithm, linear-diophantine-equations

My task requires some euclidian work beforehand

> gcd(4386, 89744) = 4386 x + 89744 y

I've confirmed that

> gcd(4386, 89744) = 2

Does that mean that

> 4386 x + 89744 y = 2?

I ask because this format is the basis of a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjliV5u2IVw) tutorial.

Comment: Yes. For some values of $x$ and $y$, it is true, provided your gcd is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does clearly not mean that for any $x,y$ : $4386 x + 89744 y = 2$ if it's what you meant. What is true is that the equation $4386 x + 89744 y = 2$ has an integer solution, that is: there are $x,y$ so that $4386 x + 89744 y = 2$ (namely $x = 22569, y = -1103$).

In general: If you have gcd(a,b)=c then the equation $ax +by = c$ has an integer solution.

Comment: I haven't touched upon looking for more than one yet, but good to know.

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm to find the gcd also gives you a way to find a particular x,y. All the  other solutions are of the form  x-nb/c,  y+na/c for integer n.